# Accidentally Removed POP3 Email On Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, pop3

So what's happened is I have removed my POP3 email account from Outlook 2010 and I'm not sure why, maybe it's because it is my default email account, but everything is still there. It's just not receiving emails and I can't send anything.

The problem is I didn't realise the difference between POP3 and IMAP until I tried to just add the account again under IMAP settings and nothing showed up as there were no emails backed up on the server.

This is a work email so it's pretty important that I have all the emails from my original POP3 email account (which is still showing up in my Outlook).

If I add the same email address with IMAP settings, copy my inbox from the old account to the new account, set the new one as default and remove the old one - will emails start automatically coming to the new account? Will that work?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So is the account there or not there? You seem to be saying a few different things. If this is your own computer, one that doesn't actually belong to work, ask your work IT for information about configuring your work account in Outlook. Once you are receiving email from work again, you can focus on getting your old messages and new messages in the same mail files.

Answer (score 0):

What’s the detailed issue? After changing account type from POP to IMAP, you cannot find original emails?

It’s true that POP3 and IMAP using different ways to save emails. For POP account, emails should be downloaded to a local data file and removed from server. While, IMAP account sync emails with server.

So, we need to find original .pst files and then import them back to your account. Please search this on your computer.

I found [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b31a9b42-a469-439c-8faa-5996f63a0bdb/change-from-pop3-to-imap?forum=outlook) in Technet forum. You can check Steve’s reply regarding how to move data from POP to IMAP.